# Flash object not autoplaying (tumblr)

Tags: html, css, flash, embed

I have a flash object I need to embed on my tumblr blog ([Billy's audio player](http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/)) and the embed works fine, except that I need to click a white play button before the object works:
[image]

(this is in Chrome; there is a similar play button on Edge)

However, other websites don't have this play button over the widget, including the widget's own webpage and the bottom left of [this blog](http://le4f.tumblr.com/post/25435014667/billy-music-player-sheep-productions-alternate).

This is the embed code, taken directly from the Billy's audio player webpage (with added newlines for readability):

```
<embed src="http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/billy.swf?autoplay=true&amp;f0=http://www.sheepproductions.com/sammy.mp3&amp;t0=Sammy&amp;total=1" 
quality="high" wmode="transparent" width="200" height="10" name="billy" 
align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" title="Adobe Flash Player">
```

Is there something I can add to make the flash object run automatically? I doubt it's a browser issue, as it works on some other webpages, and other viewers also see the white play button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, other websites don't have this play button... including the
>   widget's own webpage.

SWF and HTML must be in **the same exact location** (ie: web folder).

If SWF url is : `http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/billy.swf` 
then HTML must be : `http://www.sheepproductions.com/billy/pageWithSWFembeded.html`

This issue is caused by the small width/height of your SWF. Browsers assume it is a Flash advert banner and do not auto-load it. It can be fixed by either increasing SWF display size or by putting the small SWF in same location as HTML page that loads the SWF.

Also consider using HTML5 audio tag to guarantee playback of website audio even on mobile devices (they don't run Flash content within default browsers).